# Haskell on a Mac: Can Stack and Cabal be installed in the same Mac?

Tags: macos, haskell, package, cabal, haskell-stack

I just got a new Macbook, so I've installed Xcode, Homebrew, Haskell-Stack and Git.  And because I wanted to use some Haskell tools based on Cabal, I also installed Cabal.  However, the tools didn't work.  So I tried to reinstall Stack and Haskell again, which might have resulted in more corruption of the system files.  My questions are:

- Can Stack and Cabal be installed in the same Mac?  If it's a yes, how do we go about doing that and ensure that dependent packages work?

**Installation Process**

First, I installed Xcode after setting up my AppleID.
Then, the installation process is as follows:

```
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew install haskell-stack
brew install git
brew install cabal-install
cabal update
cabal install simple-reflect --lib
exec zsh
ghci`
```

ghci threw an error:
`GHCi, version 8.10.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help Loaded package environment from /Users/maxloo/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-8.10.1/environments/default ghc: can't find a package database at /Users/maxloo/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.1/package.db`

I also tried the following commands to check the installations:

```
`maxloo@MAXLOORM6KM ~ % which cabal
/usr/local/bin/cabal
maxloo@MAXLOORM6KM ~ % cabal --version
cabal-install version 3.2.0.0
compiled using version 3.2.0.0 of the Cabal library 
maxloo@MAXLOORM6KM ~ % which ghc
/usr/local/bin/ghc
maxloo@MAXLOORM6KM ~ % ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.1`
```

Comment: They should co-install fine, Stack does not install anything outside of the user directory by default. Cabal/GHC/Haskell Platform may have more system integration, but that should not matter to Stack. How did you install them and what did you corrupt?

Comment: ok, i've updated my post to include the initial part of the installation process .. i'm not exactly sure i've corrupted anything, but ghci doesn't run after i've installed cabal and the simple-reflect tool. i'm now uninstalling cabal and haskell using instructions from https://gist.github.com/gatlin/3862648

Comment: This sounds silly but you should try running `cabal install simple-reflect --lib` from zsh, it should create that `/Users/maxloo/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.1/package.db` for you. It sounds like a bug that it wasn't created in the first place